How to set up an Asus Vivobook laptop with dual monitors.?
I just bought a new Asus Vivobook (model X1404Z) laptop, and I am trying to set up dual monitors. I have 2 monitors and using a docking station that had 2 ports. I have it all set up correctly because my old Dell laptop works with it but when I connect the new laptop it will not recognize the 2nd monitor.
I have been working on this for 3 nights now.  I have all cables connected but will not recognize the 2nd monitor.  I do not want to use the laptop screen so keep the laptop closed so only wanting to use the 2 monitors.

Intel 12th generation Core i3
Intel Iris Xe Graphics
Graphics Type Integrated

Monitors are both Samsung and docking station is hp.  I have also tried 2 different USB-C hub docking stations that have 2 hdmi ports.

Does you laptop support 3 monitors (internal + 2 external)? It may not... Start by [edit]ing your question and add the actual model -and- hardware specifications, namely graphics, and the monitors' models, dock and conncetions.

How do I find the model and hardware specifications???

These will be in the system's details, on the ASUS support site, documentation, or in Settings > System. While it can be frustrating, it is important to keep in mind that just because a computer has the same-shape ports does not mean it supports everything that could connect to those ports.
